# React Native Android: Manifest merger failed

Tags: android, react-native

When I am running the command  react-native run-android in the terminal 
(React-Native), I am getting the below-mentioned error.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(andr
>   oid.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compa
>   t:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha05] AndroidManifest.xm
>   l:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).

I tried migrating from android.support to android x as per the solution stated by few.

> Expected Result: Build SuccessFul
>
> Actual Result: BUILD FAILED in 9s

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding below in `gradle.properties`:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

It will automatically resolve dependency conflicts between google's files and third-party dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

see [Manifest merger failed after import a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803943/manifest-merger-failed-after-import-a-module/56853863#56853863) if this option doesnt work rather than upgrading to android X now.